# Render flask template by clicking dynamically generated list item and passing 1 parameter to the back end

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

Ok so I am working with 2 ideas here and running into roadblocks on both... need guidance on which one is best and how to make this work.

The general idea is that I am dynamically generating a string of HTML which adds a list item. the user can select a list object and this will pass data from that list item that will be sent to flask, worked on a little bit, then a template is rendered with parameters based on the data we received from the user input.

Let's look at an example of the two ideas I'm working off of and where I am running into trouble.

In both cases, we are dynamically creating a list based in JS based on some input we receive from the user.

The first idea is to add a button with an onclick event that passes the bar as the parameter.

```
var data = "<ul>";
    var max= Object.keys(res.foo).length;
      for(var i = 0; i< max; i++){
        let bar= (res["bar"][i]);
        let foo = res["foo"][i];
        data += "<li>"+foo+" <button type='button' onclick = 'sendBar(this.id)' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='"+bar+"'>></button></li>";
    };
             
              data += "</ul>";
              $("#datalist").html(data);
```

I have a function with the goal of sending the data to the back end

```
function sendBar(Bar){
    fetch("/foo-bar", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ Bar: Bar}),
    success: function(response){
      this.window.location.href = '/foo-bar'
    }
    });
}
```

With this data, the goal is to query the database and grab some data based on the value that is posted.

```
@views.route('/foo-bar', methods=['POST'])
def fooBar():
    data= json.loads(request.data)
    Bar= data['Bar']
    sql = "SELECT * Foobar FROM foobar where bar ='"+Bar+ "'" 
    fooBar_data=db.engine.execute(sql)
    df = pd.DataFrame(foobar_data, columns = ['foobar','foo','bar'])
    return render_template("foobar.html", data = df.to_html(classes ='table table-striped'))
```

this is not working. I have seen in some places this is not a good use of ajax. Clearly I'm not really sure either way.

The other idea is instead of using a button/onclick event... just render the template using {{url_for('views.fooBar',Bar = Bar)}}

I think I am running into trouble figuring out how to put this into the string builder I am working with in JS... it's such a mess with quotes and I feel like I may need to escape the jinja call, but I don't know how. here is what I was playing with.

```
data += "<li><a href ="+'{{ url_for("views.fooBar",Bar = Bar) }}'+">" + res["note"][i]+"</a></li>";
```

obviously this is not the right way to do this... maybe someone can help me formulate this string in the proper way so that I may try this approach and see if I can get my desired result?

Or maybe someone has a better idea.  thanks !

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just passing the raw data from flask back to the front end via an AJAX call and then parsing it with client side JS?

Comment: The main reason is because I'm not really sure what I'm doing, but I was able to solve my problem by turning it into a form, thus the post request from the button click triggers the back end to render the template, which is what I wanted.